# django right-to-left language with LANGUAGE_BIDI does not work

Tags: django, internationalization, multilingual

I am building a multi-language site with one of the languages "farsi":
Everything worked fine so far, but the right to left language "farsi/persian" is not aligned right, when beginning a next line of text. That means the next line is not aligned at the right as usual for right-to-left languages.
The translation work.

**settings.py**

```
gettext = lambda s: s

#default language should be german
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa'


LANGUAGES = (
    #('fr', gettext('French')),
    ('de', gettext('German')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('fa', gettext('Farsi')),
    #('pt-br', gettext("Brazil")),
)
```

**language_chooser.html**

```
{% load localeurl_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load tabs %} 


{% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
        {% ifequal lang.0 LANGUAGE_CODE %}
           <li class="active"><a>{{ lang.1 }}</a></li>
        {% else %}

<!--
        {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
          <li>The current language is bidirectional</li>
        {% else %}
          <li>The current language is <b>not</b> bidirectional</li>
        {% endif %}
-->
           <li class="{% ifactivetab "en" %}active{% else %}inactive{% endifactivetab %}"><a href="{{ request.path|chlocale:lang.0 }}" accesskey="2">{{ lang.1 }}</a></li>
        {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

in the **base.html** I also load:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
```

My **django.po** file for "farsi/persian" language looks like:
[image]

How can I manage this?

**Solution:**
After defining a new css class "article_right_aligned_language" with the attribute "text-align:right; direction:rtl" and modifying my base template as follows, it works now !!

```
      <div {% if LANGUAGE_BIDI %} class="article_right_aligned_language" {% else %} class="article" {% endif %}>
        {% block site_wrapper %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Text alignment is handled by CSS not Django. Set the `text-align` property on the container element:

```
.container.right-aligned-language {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Then you can apply the class `right-aligned-language` to your container (or body tag for that matter) with a conditional statement in your template.

Answer (score 3):

nowadays you should use in CSS:

```
direction: rtl
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_direction.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead please:

https://github.com/abbas123456/django-right-to-left

CSS is for style and not content.